# Springboot cannot find templates

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, thymeleaf

it is my controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login(){
        System.out.println("hello");
        return "user/login";
    }
}
```

and it is my yaml file

```
spring:
  thymeleaf:
    check-template-location: true
    prefix: classpath:/templates/
    suffix: .html
    cache: false
    mode: HTML
    encoding: utf-8
```

and it is my directory tree

```
├─src
│  ├─main
│  │  ├─java
│  │  │  └─com
│  │  │      └─example
│  │  │          └─facebook
│  │  │              ├─controller
│  │  │              ├─dao
│  │  │              ├─model
│  │  │              └─service
│  │  └─resources
│  │      ├─mapper
│  │      ├─static
│  │      └─templates
│  │          ├─hello
│  │          └─user
|                └─ login.html
│  └─test
│      └─java
│          └─com
│              └─example
│                  └─facebook
```

but... my project cant find login.html with 404 error, but print hello in console...
how can i fix it?

Comment: The configuration you did in YAML should not be needed normally. What exact URL are you trying to access in the browser? Is there any exception printed?

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention that the controller prints the "hello" string, the mapping is working. Have you added thymeleaf dependency to your pom file?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```